# Call default method of R after overriding

Tags: r

I am in process of learning R. I realized we can override method some very basic methods like c() which is used to create vectors or even print() method.

This brings me to thought what if we build some methods and later on during modification/ development, we import some library and found same methods exist in library. There will be contradiction and our methods will be executed instead of library methods. Or if accidentally, we build some methods whose name is similar to default methods. How will we be detecting the contradicted methods. Or how will we invoke both these methods separately according to our needs?

In other languages like Java/ dotnet/ cpp, we make classes and override methods in them. So we can distinguish via objects. But I see, here in R, we can directly start making our R-objects and related methods without much encapsulation.

Sorry for asking naive question. I am still in process of grasping whatever info I can get.

Comment: Don't override default methods

Comment: Don't override default methods

Comment: Study package namespaces. You can define a `print` function (you shouldn't), but you can't (easily) "override" `base::print`.

Comment: Ah, there I got. Thanks Roland. Well tutpoint is missing this info then :)

Comment: Also, don't ever name your function something someone else might name their function sometime in the future.